# SpaCy loading models

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am new to NLP and spaCy. I am using the `en_core_web_md` model. I am loading it using `spacy.load()` 

 Whenever I run my program it loads the model. Is there a way to load the model just once for all the subsequent runs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, in the example code below

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')  # make sure to use larger model!
tokens = nlp(u'dog cat banana')

for token1 in tokens:
    for token2 in tokens:
        print(token1.text, token2.text, token1.similarity(token2))
```

keep the variable `nlp` save since it contains model. 
and you can pass `nlp`again and again by just passing it through your required function.

Comment: Ok I understand that but what if I want to deploy the app over web how will it work then? Thanks for replying. I just want to know if we search a query over the web the each time a user send the query the model will be loaded?

Comment: You need to understand "ML as a service" .  When you to start you backend server it should load up the model and when every it receives a "post-get" request it just use that model variable to perform the required operation.

Comment: You might find this repo useful: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-services/ It includes several simple examples of serving spaCy and its capabilities over a REST API. Here, the loaded models are stored in a global variable. When you run the `app.py`, the models are loaded and kept in memory.